# OpenGL app not working properly on Nexus 7

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, texture-mapping, nexus-7

I've written an application that displays an OpenGL `SurfaceView` next to a `ListView` and although the application works perfectly on both a Samsung Galaxy SIII and a Samsung Galaxy Nexus, exact same application, whenever I deploy it on an Asus Nexus 7 the `SurfaceView` is either not there or the texture is not being drawn on it. What could be the source of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Your textures have to have a size to the power of two, like 128 x 128, or 512 x 1024, and so on.

Source: [Android OpenGLES 1.0 game displays black screen on Nexus 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305116/android-opengles-1-0-game-displays-black-screen-on-nexus-7)