# Android OpenGLES 1.0 game displays black screen on Nexus 7

Tags: android, opengl-es, nexus-7

I've made a game that uses OpenGL 1.0 on Android. It works fine on my Android 2.3 phone but displays a black screen on my nexus 7 (now Android 4.4). The music and sound seem to be working fine just the display is black. I'm wondering what the possible issues could be. This is hard to debug because there are no error messages that I can see. Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: Does it works under 4.3 emulator?

Comment: Yes it works on an emulated Nexus 7 with Android 4.3

Comment: I'd suggest looking closely at the logcat output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe too old question. But I met same issue on Nexus 7 first generation. 
I rescaled all textures to size power of 2 like 128x128, 256x256, 512x512 etc. and problem got solved.

Comment: I had seen this answer in another similar question and had discounted it but surprisingly it was the answer. Changing each .png texture in my game to a power of 2 size fixed everything. Thank you.